# How to view string as it is being entered in keyring::key_set()

Tags: r, keyring

When I type into the pop-up triggered by `key_set()` I am unable to view the text I am typing. Is there a way to override this default feature that masks the string, or toggle it on & off so that users can check their spelling without having to use `key_get()`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `keyring`-package is dependent on the package `askpass` (https://github.com/r-lib/askpass). The answer is OS dependent, but for MacOS (as you use) you could do as follows.

Navigate to the package library (use `.libPaths()`), find the package library   for `askpass` and edit the file `mac-simplepass` with a suitable text editor. Find `line 7`.

**Remove:**
`with hidden answer`

**That gives a new line 7:**
`display dialog args with icon note default button "OK" default answer ""`

You may need to restart.

That being said, however, consider using `keyring::key_set_with_value()` without the prompt, if you need to see what you're writing.

Comment: keyring::key_set_with_value() requires a service argument, but I am unclear that this is as the definition is fairly circular "Service name, a character scalar."

Comment: `keyring::key_set` and `keyring::key_set_with_value()` takes the same arguments besides the first is using a prompt and the second takes it as an argument. The `service` argument is the same in both. It's "the name" as it will appear in the keychain.